# Pytorch: Can’t load images using ImageFolder

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m trying to load images using “ImageFolder”.

```
data_dir = './train_dog'          # directory structure is    
train_dog/image
dset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
```

However, it seems not working. So I checked the stored data as below

```
print dset[0][0]
```

Then it shows only 3 tensors(size 64x64).

```
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x64x64]
```

There are more than 10,000 images in the folder. How come it can’t store all data?

Comment: You should improve your post, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
print len(dset)
```

which represents the size of the dataset, aka the number of image files.

`dset[0]` means the (shuffled) first index of the dataset, where `dset[0][0]` contains the input image tensor and `dset[0][1]` contains the corresponding label or target.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. But it shows   File "gan_scratch.py", line 258, in <module>
        mini_batch = x_.size()[0]
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: x_ contains images loaded above, but why aren't they tensor but list?